# I can't create realtime database in firebase , android

Tags: android

this my first time writing an android app connected with firebase; 
I wrote this code for my chat activity, the problem is, when I try to write a msg and send this msg it's not updated in the real-time database 
and my real-time database is empty, and I don't know how can I add child 
or add the users in my real-time database, please help me.

```
public class users_fragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView ;
    private UserAdapter userAdapter;
    private List<User> mUsers ;
    private DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();;
    DatabaseReference users = mRootRef.child("users");

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        readUsers();
        return view;
    }

    private void readUsers(){
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        //DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    assert user != null;
                    assert firebaseUser != null;
                    if (!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                        mUsers.add(user);

                    }
                }

                userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext() , mUsers);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here is my database :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like you are attempting to create something from nothing in that
>   code. you are adding a user who is in your database which has not been
>   added yet. Now, The reference is ok.
>
> > to add a user det
> >
> > > userId = datRef.push.getkey();
> > >       User mUser = new User(userId, userName);
> > >       datRef.child(userId).setValue(mUser)
> > >
> > > To read from the database, now you can implement
> > >       datRef.addValueEventListener(valueeventlistener)

Comment: thank you, but what did you mean by userId ? is it a FirebaseUser? also, darRef means reference?

Comment: userId is a unique Id that will identify that entry, which is generated by the push. Yes I mean the samr reference by darRef. In that code, 'User' is a class you create.